# Get all child links from anchor node

Tags: selenium, xpath, watir

I have a `ul` with child links that are buried a few levels down, what is the best way to extract them with xpath or [watir](http://watir.com/guides/locating/)?

```
browser.element(xpath: "//h3/following-sibling::ul[1]//a").html
and 
browser.element(xpath: "//h3/following-sibling::ul[1]").a.href
```

will get me the first the first link, but not all of them. How can you extract all links?

I've tried `browser.element(xpath: "//h3/following-sibling::ul[1]//*[@href]")` but it also only gives me the first element

Comment: how about `browser.as(css: 'h3 + ul a')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the `#as` or `#links` method on the `ul` element, Watir will return all child links, regardless of how many levels down they are. From there, you can iterate over the links to get the href.

```
browser.element(xpath: "//h3/following-sibling::ul[1]").as.map(&:href)
#=> ["href1", "href2", "etc"]
```

If you want to avoid XPath, you can also do:

```
browser.h3.following_sibling(tag_name: 'ul').as.map(&:href)
```